# Why my bokeh server app won't update the figure

Tags: python, bokeh

here's my data ：https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CabmdDQucaKW2XhBxQlXVNOSiNRtkMm-?usp=sharing
i want to use the select to choose the stock i want to show; 
and slider to choose the year range i want to show; 
and checkboxgroup to choose the index i want to compare with.
the problem is when i adjust the slider, the figure will update, but when i use the select and checkboxgroup, the figure won't update, 
what's the reason?

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider, TextInput , Select , Div, CheckboxGroup
from bokeh.plotting import figure
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

price=pd.read_excel('price.xlsx',index_col=0)
# input control

stock = Select(title='Stock',value='AAPL',options=[x for x in list(price.columns) if x not in ['S&P','DOW']])
yr_1 = Slider(title='Start year',value=2015,start=2000,end=2020,step=1)
yr_2 = Slider(title='End year',value=2020,start=2000,end=2020,step=1)
index = CheckboxGroup(labels=['S&P','DOW'],active=[0,1])

def get_data():
    compare_index = [index.labels[i] for i in index.active]
    stocks = stock.value
    start_year = str(yr_1.value)
    end_year = str(yr_2.value)

    select_list = []
    select_list.append(stocks)
    select_list.extend(compare_index)
    selected = price[select_list]
    selected = selected [start_year:end_year]
    for col in selected.columns:
        selected[col]=selected[col]/selected[col].dropna()[0]

    return ColumnDataSource(selected)

def make_plot(source):
    fig=figure(plot_height=600, plot_width=700, title="",sizing_mode="scale_both", x_axis_type="datetime")
    data_columns = list(source.data.keys())
    for data in data_columns[1:]:
        fig.line(x=data_columns[0],y=data,source=source,line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6, legend_label=data)
    return fig

def update(attrname, old, new):
    new_source = get_data()

    source.data.clear()
    source.data.update(new_source.data)


#get the initial value and plot
source = get_data()
plot = make_plot(source)

#control_update

stock.on_change('value', update)
yr_1.on_change('value', update)
yr_2.on_change('value', update)
index.on_change('active', update)


# Set up layouts and add to document
inputs = column(stock, yr_1, yr_2, index)

curdoc().add_root(row(inputs, plot, width=800))
curdoc().title = "Stocks"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new `ColumnDataSource` for new data. That's not a good approach.
Instead, create it once and then just assign its `data` as appropriate.

In your case, I would do it like this:

1. Create `ColumnDataSource` just once, as described above
2. Do not use `.update` on CDS, just reassign `.data`
3. Create the legend manually
4. For that one line that's susceptible to the select change choose a static `x` field and use it everywhere instead
5. Change the first legend item's label when you change the select's value to instead of that `x` field it has the correct name